# MySQL INNER JOIN of 3 tables with count and totals

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sample database set up -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `companies`(
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `companies` (`id`, `company`) VALUES
(1, 'Acme Widget Company'),
(2, 'Intrepid Inc.'),
(3, 'Allied Corp.');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `companies_customers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `companies_customers` (`id`, `company_id`, `customer_id`) VALUES
(1, 2, 1),
(2, 2, 2),
(3, 2, 4),
(4, 1, 3),
(5, 1, 1);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `customers` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`)   VALUES
(1, 'John', 'Smith'),
(2, 'Sue', 'Jones'),
(3, 'David', 'Flanders'),
(4, 'Kathy', 'Freeman');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders`  (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES
(1, 1, 500),
(2, 3, 1000),
(3, 1, 250),
(4, 4, 800),
(5, 4, 100);
```

I need to write a query which retrieves a list of *all* company names, a count of the number of customers in each company, and a sum of the customers orders in each company, like this -

```
Company                 Total Customers All Orders Total
Acme Widget Company     2               750
Intrepid Inc.           3               1650
Allied Corp.            0               0
```

I nearly have it resolved with the following SQL -

```
SELECT company AS 'Company', customersCount AS 'Total Customers', customerOrdersTotal AS 'All Orders Total'
  FROM
  ( SELECT cc.customer_id, SUM(innerQuery.ordersTotal) customerOrdersTotal
    FROM (SELECT cu.id customerId, SUM(amount) ordersTotal
          FROM customers cu
          JOIN orders o ON o.customer_id = cu.id
          GROUP BY customerId
         ) innerQuery
    JOIN companies_customers cc ON innerQuery.customerId = cc.customer_id
    GROUP BY cc.customer_id
  ) inner_1
  RIGHT JOIN 
    ( SELECT cc.id, c.company, COUNT(*) customersCount
      FROM companies c
      JOIN companies_customers cc ON c.id = cc.company_id
      GROUP BY c.id
    ) inner_2
  ON inner_1.customer_id = inner_2.id
```

It does not print out the company (Allied) without a customer or total.  So close, I just need a nudge in the right direction.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the orders are linked to the companies *via* the customers, I don't think you need to perform two separate subqueries and join them; rather, I think you can just write:

```
SELECT companies.company AS "Company",
       IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT companies_customers.customer_id), 0) AS "Total Customers",
       IFNULL(SUM(orders.amount), 0) AS "All Orders Total"
  FROM companies
  LEFT
  JOIN companies_customers
    ON companies_customers.company_id = companies.id
  LEFT
  JOIN orders
    ON orders.customer_id = companies_customers.customer_id
 GROUP
    BY companies.id
;
```

**Edited to add:** That said, I have to say that the schema doesn't really make sense to me. You have a many-to-many relationship between customers and companies — so, for example, `John Smith` is a customer of `Acme Widget Company` *and* of `Intrepid Inc.` — but then orders are just a property of the customer, *not* of the company. This means that if an order belongs to `John Smith`, then it necessarily belongs *both* to `Acme Widget Company` *and* to `Intrepid Inc.`. I don't think that can be right. Instead of having a `customer_id` field, I think `orders` needs to have a `companies_customers_id` field.

Comment: I am needing totals of thte "amount" column per company, not a COUNT(1) of orders placed.  So, I think that stills requires a sub-select?  Your solution results in  9 (3+5+1) for "All Orders Total".  That is not correct as there are only 5 rows in the orders table.  Yeah, I agree on order needing a companies_customers_id  field.

Comment: So, I have come up with this modification of your SQL - <pre>SELECT companies.company AS "Company",
  IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT companies_customers.customer_id), 0) AS "Total Customers",
  COUNT(1) AS "Total Orders Placed",
  SUM(orders.amount) AS 'Total Value of Orders'
  FROM companies
  LEFT JOIN companies_customers ON companies_customers.company_id = companies.id
  LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.customer_id = companies_customers.customer_id
 GROUP BY companies.id</pre>

Comment: Sorry about the bad formatting - can't seem to figure how to make the <pre> tag apply in these replies.

Comment: Re: totals of the "amount" column: Duh, sorry, that should have been obvious. I've updated the query in my answer to use `IFNULL(SUM(orders.amount), 0)` instead of `COUNT(1)`. Re: <pre>: it's not supported in comments. You can get monospaced text by using backticks, `\``, but that doesn't preserve extra spaces and line-breaks and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 table that to keep `team`,`tournament_round` AND `score_team_member` about competition TEAM_A Vs TEAM_B ,multiple of round.(1,2,3...n) and multiple of members of team there is score by oneself.This code above are useful very much.

```
SELECT team.name AS "TEAM",team.id,
       IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT `tournament_round`.id), 0) AS "TotalWin",
       IFNULL(SUM(`score_team_member`.`score`)/(select count(*) from `team_member`where team_id=team.id group by team_id ), 0) AS "ScoreofTeam"
  FROM `team`
  LEFT
  JOIN `tournament_round`
    ON `tournament_round`.team_winner_id = `team`.id 
  LEFT
  JOIN `score_team_member`
    ON `score_team_member`.team_id = `team`.id
WHERE `team`.thematch_id='6' AND `team`.`category1`='MEP'
 GROUP    BY `team`.id ORDER by `TotalWin`DESC ,`ScoreofTeam` DESC
```

[Sample out put click here JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efP8v.png)

[Table Designer JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSi8M.png)