# How to join 1 table to another table and get count result per date

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have 3 tables with corresponding fields.

Table 1 (List of Machines)

```
Machine_No   |    Machine_Description 
1            |    Hitachi    
2            |    Jet Printer
3            |    Sumi
```

Table 2 (List of Manpower)

```
ID_Number    |  Employee_Name   | Machine_No
1            |  Taylor          | 3
2            |  James           | 2
3            |  David           | 1
```

Table 3 (Actual Manpower use per machine)

```
Machine_No    |    Employee_Number   |     Date Posted
1             |    1                 |     15-10-2019
1             |    2                 |     15-10-2019
1             |    3                 |     15-10-2019
```

Now... I want the results to go like this.

```
Machine_Now    |   Count(Employee Number)    |   Date_Posted
1              |   3                         |   15-10-2019
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL INNER JOIN of 3 tables with count and totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772458/mysql-inner-join-of-3-tables-with-count-and-totals)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it may work, if I understand your question correctly.

`select Machine_No,Date_Posted,count(*) from Table3 group by Machine_No,Date_Posted;`